# How to style tables dynamically using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to have the tables inside this snippet to be styled dynamically? Instead of splitting the data fetched each time and hardcoding it? They have different number of columns and rows. I'd like them to have the same style using only one `split()`, so I can have my code DRY. The approach to the solution would be on a complete different way than my code is written now? Thank you very much for the help.

```js
function loadMountsVehicles() {
    fetch('https://api.open5e.com/sections/mounts-and-vehicles/'
    ).then(function (responses) {
        return responses.json();
    }).then(function (data) {
        displayMountsVehicles(data);
    });
};

function displayMountsVehicles(data) {
    let html = "";
    html += `<h3>Mounts and Vehicles</h3>`;
    for (let i = 0; i < data.desc.split(/\n/).length; i++) {
        if (i < 16) {
            html += `<p>${data.desc.split(/\n/)[i]}</p>`;
        }
    };

    let mountsTable = data.desc.split(/[\n|]+/).splice(8, 40);
    let index = mountsTable.indexOf("----------------");
    if (index > -1) {
        mountsTable.splice(index, 4);
    };
    let perrow = 4;
    html += "<table><thead><tr>";
    for (let i = 0; i < mountsTable.length; i++) {
        html += `<td>${mountsTable[i]}</td>`;
        let next = i + 1;
        if (i === 3) {
            html += `</thead>`;
        } else if (next % perrow == 0 && next != mountsTable.length) {
            html += "</tr><tr>";
        }
    };
    html += "</tr></table>";

    for (let i = 0; i < data.desc.split(/\n/).length; i++) {
        if (i < 28 && i > 25) {
            html += `<p>${data.desc.split(/\n/)[i]}</p>`;
        }
    };

    let tackTable = data.desc.split(/[\n|]+/).splice(49, 51);
    let indexTack = tackTable.indexOf("--------------------");
    if (indexTack > -1) {
        tackTable.splice(indexTack, 3);
    };
    let perrowTack = 3;
    html += "<table><thead><tr>";
    for (let i = 0; i < tackTable.length; i++) {
        html += `<td>${tackTable[i]}</td>`;
        let next = i + 1;
        if (i === 2) {
            html += `</thead>`;
        } else if (next % perrowTack == 0 && next != tackTable.length) {
            html += "</tr><tr>";
        }
    };
    html += "</tr></table>";

    for (let i = 0; i < data.desc.split(/\n/).length; i++) {
        if (i > 45 && i < 49) {
            html += `<p>${data.desc.split(/\n/)[i]}</p>`;
        }
    };

    let waterboneTable = data.desc.split(/[\n|]+/).splice(101);
    let indexWaterbone = waterboneTable.indexOf("--------------");
    if (indexWaterbone > -1) {
        waterboneTable.splice(indexWaterbone, 3);
    };
    let perrowWaterbone = 3;
    html += "<table><thead><tr>";

    for (let i = 0; i < waterboneTable.length; i++) {
        html += `<td>${waterboneTable[i]}</td>`;
        let next = i + 1;
        if (i === 2) {
            html += `</thead>`;
        } else if (next % perrowWaterbone == 0 && next != waterboneTable.length) {
            html += "</tr><tr>";
        }
    };
    html += "</tr></table>";
    html = html.replace(/\*\*\_([\w\(\)][\s\w\,\(\)\.]+)\_\*\*/g, "<span>$1</span>");
    html = html.replace(/\*\*([\w\(\)\_][\s\w\,\(\)\_\.]+)\*\*/g, "<span>$1</span>");
    document.querySelector(".content-text").innerHTML = html;
};
```

```html
<body onload="loadMountsVehicles()"> 
    <div class="content-text"></div>
</body>
```

This is the data returned from the API:

```js
function loadMountsVehicles() {
    fetch('https://api.open5e.com/sections/mounts-and-vehicles/'
    ).then(function (responses) {
        return responses.json();
    }).then(function (data) {
        console.log(data.desc)
    });
};
```

```html
 <body onload="loadMountsVehicles()">
 </body>
```

Comment: can you please post a sample of the data returned by the  `mounts-and-vehicles` api?

Comment: Hi. I've just added a snippet with a log. I hope this is enough. Thank you very much.

Comment: Almost like you want a [markdown renderer](https://github.com/markedjs/marked).

Comment: Nice! I think that is it. I've just learned something new. Thanks ever so much!

Comment: @Wyck what a briliant idea!